# Null reference in Unreal Engine core code?

Tags: unreal-engine5

I am trying to build my solution in vs2022 for my project in ue5, yet i can not do it because vs2022 shows me errors in epic games core code? The red marker is to hide my user name and project name, i don't know the rules, sorry for that if it wrong.

[image]

All the best!

I did install everything what Documentation in unreal engine 5 told me to, to set up UE5.
I did enable plugin in ue5 for vs and changed default ide for vs2022.
I did install vs tool in epic games.
I did configure ue5 in vs2022 as it told me to.
I did build/rebuild/generate project multiple times (by deleting .vs intermediate binaries saved...)
I did refreshing in ue5.
I did changing errors to build only / build + intelii - does shows only different errors :/.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: This is a known issue: https://github.com/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/pull/11110

Comment: @UnholySheep That URL gives me a 404 error, it's not a public repo (or you posted a bad URL).

Comment: @PeterB right, forgot you need to have your Github account linked to EpicGames for their repo. Here's the corresponding forum post: https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/error-compiling-the-automation-tool-after-updating-visual-studio-today-unreal-5-3-2/1393088

Comment: @JamesYou seem to be building with "Warning as Errors", or at least this is the case for CS8604. You either need to convince the compiler that **`users`** can never be null by assigning it a value, or add an "is not null"-check for `users`, or else perhaps disable/suppress the CS8604 warning (but then you may be at risk for a runtime error).

Comment: I don't understand, if there is a fix in epic code... by epic... why wont they fix it for everyone when you install their engine? --- This helped, thank you! But i have a problem with last one, i have search epic forums, found many threads, but it did not work for me yet.  The command ""C:\Program Files\EpicGames\UE_5.3\Engine\Build\BatchFiles\Build.bat" xxxEditor Win64 Development -Project="C:\Users\xxx\OneDrive\Pulpit\xxx\xxx.uproject" -WaitMutex -FromMsBuild" exited with code 6.

Comment: For code 6 if someone will have same problem - https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/ue5-1-vs2022-c-build-error-with-msb3073/694392/6. It fixed it by turning off live coding and rebuilding project. For epic code errors: https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/error-compiling-the-automation-tool-after-updating-visual-studio-today-unreal-5-3-2/1393088. End of my problems for now :)